# The cohomology ring of two tori glued along the first circle

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be the space consisting of two tori glued along the first circle: I interpret the space as  $X=S^1_{(1)}\times S^1_{(2)}\sqcup S^1_{(3)}\times S^1_{(4)} / (S^1_{(1)}\sim  S^1_{(3)})$. I want to compute its cohomology (over, say, the integers). I have two ideas for this:

1. Use the long exact sequence of the quotient on $(X,S^1_{(1)})$

For the first approach, I have two preliminary steps that I'm not sure of: first, the quotient of the torus $S^1\times S^1/S^1\times \{e\}$ by its first circle is just the circle. If that's the case, then the quotient $X/S^1$ is the wedge sum of two circles $S^1\vee S^1$. But then the LES of the quotient is:

$$0\to \tilde H^1(S^1\vee S^1)\to \tilde H^1(X)\to \tilde H^1(S^1)\to \tilde H^2(S^1\vee S^1)\to \tilde H^2(X)\to \tilde H^2(S^1)\to \tilde H^3(S^1\vee S^1)\to \tilde H^3(X)\to \tilde H^3(S^1)\to 0$$

But $\tilde H^n(S^1\vee S^1)= \tilde H^n(S^1)\oplus \tilde H^n(S^1)$, hence the LES becomes:

$$0\to \mathbb Z^2\to \tilde H^1(X)\to\mathbb Z\to 0 \to \tilde H^2(X)\to 0\to 0\to \tilde H^3(X)\to 0\to 0$$

Which looks completely wrong, since we get $\tilde H^1(X)=\mathbb Z^3$ and $0$ otherwise.

2. Use Mayer-Vietoris on $X$ by taking as my two subspaces each torus.

For the second approach, the intersection of the tori in $X$ is just $S^1$, so Mayer Vietoris gives:

$$0\to H^0(X)\to H^0(A)\oplus H^0(B)\to H^0(A\cap B)\to H^1(X)\to H^1(A)\oplus H^1(B)\to H^1(A\cap B)\to H^2(X)\to H^2(A)\oplus H^0(B)\to H^2(A\cap B)\to 0$$
Which gives

$$0\to \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z^2\to \mathbb Z\to H^1(X)\to \mathbb Z^4\to \mathbb Z\to H^2(X)\to \mathbb Z^2\to 0\to 0$$

After some playing around this last sequence then would (could?) imply that $H^1\cong \mathbb Z^4$ and $H^2\cong \mathbb Z$, which looks slightly more reasonable.

What went wrong?

Comment: For 1. : if you try to see geometrically what you are doing by collapsing the first circle, you should convince yourself that this can not make a circle. Indeed you just get a torus that is "pinched" somewhere, this gives a kind of banana with joint ends.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking of the torus as the figure 8 space, so contracting one circle would be like killing one dimension of the torus. Of course, that is wrong since homotopy doesn't commute with quotients I suppose.

Comment: What do you mean by "homotopy don't commute with quotients" ?

Comment: Is the pinched torus homotopy equivalent to the circle? It seems to me like it is - if it is, then why would I not get the same answer?

Comment: The pinched torus his homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb S^2\vee \mathbb S^1$ (which can be see geometrically), so you can easily see (with the homology group in degree 2) that it is not homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb S^1$

Comment: @elidiot You are right, a massive blunder on my part. I'll attempt it again. However, is it still true then that the quotient $X/S^1$ of the space by the first circle is then $S^2\vee S^1\vee S^2\vee S^1$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93079/discussion-between-elidiot-and-george).